# Why do I need to add $1$ to the equation $1=\tan a+\tan b+\tan a\tan b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm preparing for make the MEXT test, I can't solve the problem.

> If $a+b=\pi/4$ then evaluate
> $$(\tan a +1)(\tan b + 1)$$

I know that

$$\tan(a+b) = 1 \tag1$$

$$1=\frac{\tan a + \tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b} \tag2$$

$$1 = \tan a + \tan b + \tan a \tan b \tag3$$

BUT, just after that I can't continue because I dont know what happen next. I saw in some webpages for help, including here, that people add 1 to both sides like

$$1 + 1 = 1 + \tan a + \tan b + \tan a \tan b \tag4$$

but why? from where comes this?.Also, after operating this how do you get to this?

$$1(1+ \tan a) + \tan b (1 + \tan a) = 2 \tag5$$

and

$$(1+ \tan a) (1 + \tan b) = 2 \tag6$$

I need to know from where comes all of this to understand.

Comment: The trick is to recognize that $p+q+pq$ is *almost* $1+p+q+pq$, which is $(1+p)(1+q)$ (a particularly convenient factorization, given the goal), so we add the needed $1$. The trick becomes less *tricky* with experience.

Comment: Expand $(\tan a + 1)(\tan b + 1)$ out and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Blue for the trick, I hadn't noticed before.

Apply the factorization for $\tan a$:

$$1 + \tan a(\tan b + 1) + \tan b$$

and before for $\tan b + 1$:

$$(1 + \tan b)(1 + \tan a).$$